# org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger

In my microservice Spring Boot application i added Swagger for my REST api's documentation. Before that my Spring Boot microservice was started fine. But When I add my add my SwaggerConfig the project can't start. I had this error :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [com.myproject.MyApplication]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [springfox/bean/validators/configuration/BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class] cannot be opened because it does not exist
```

The SwaggerConfig is in common project that add to dependency into my microservice pom.

This my project configuration

SwaggerConfig

```
package com.project.common.config;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import springfox.bean.validators.configuration.BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.ResponseMessageBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.service.ResponseMessage;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

import java.util.List;

@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Import({ BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class })
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Value("${swagger.api.title: no title}")
    private String title;
    

    @Value("${swagger.api.package}")
    private String apipackage;
    

    @Value("${swagger.api.version:no version}")
    private String version;
    

    @Value("${swagger.api.description:no description}")
    private String description;

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage(apipackage))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
                .apiInfo(new ApiInfoBuilder().title(title).description(description)
                        .version(version).build())

                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.GET,defaultResponse())
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.POST,defaultResponse())
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.PUT,defaultResponse())
                .globalResponseMessage(RequestMethod.DELETE,defaultResponse());
    }
    
    private static List<ResponseMessage> defaultResponse(){
        return 
                List.of(new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(500).message("Internal server error").build(),
                        new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(400).message("bad request").build(),
                        new ResponseMessageBuilder().code(404).message("not found").build());
    }

}
```

Main class

```
package com.project.company;

import com.project.common.config.SwaggerConfig;
import com.project.company.infrastructure.config.MyApplicationConfig;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.security.servlet.ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude={SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@Import({MyApplicationConfig.class, SwaggerConfig.class})
public class MyCompanyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyCompanyApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner init(){
        return (String... args)->{

            // do something

        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found my error. I forgot this dependency :

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
   <artifactId>springfox-bean-validators</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```